# C++ gtkmm vertical menu bar

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I am trying to make a vertical menu bar with multiple different tabs (Each tab contains multiple sub-childs and each sub-child may contain another sub-sub child) for my application which should look something like this.

[image]

However, I couldn't find a way to do it and the best I could achieve is as below using a [notebook](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-multi-item-containers.html.en#sec-notebook) widget, where I could not find a way to include any sub-child through the notebook widget.

[image]

I have also tried using [menubar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-menubar-and-toolbar.html.en) but menubar could only make a horizontal toolbar and there is no way to make it vertical.

Is there any specific widgets that I could use to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: How about a TreeView? https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en#treestore-example

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I've tried Tree View as well, but tree view display everything by rows (on both left and right side). I wanted it to be like sort of "Notebook", where all the tabs are on the left side, and you could display different stuffs on the right side. (Eg. Different buttons / icons for different tabs)

Comment: You'll need to draw out your full design for us to understand; sorry.

Comment: @andlabs Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to achieve something like this. http://www.designzzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/vertical-large.jpg

Comment: There's nothing specifically like that in GTK+, but if you have those notebooks or a GtkStackSidebar combined with a GtkStack you can create the subpages by combining GtkLabels, GtkButtons or GtkLinkButtons, and some CSS.